# C - Всегда ли использовать платформонезависимые типы данных?

Tags: c

Следует ли везде заменять классические типы данных(short, int, long) на платформонезависимые(int16_t, int32_t, int64_t) из <inttypes.h>, или следует использовать их только там, где важен точный размер переменной? Использовать ли int8_t* в строках вместо char*? Давать ли функции main тип int32_t?

Comment: Мое imho - *следует использовать их только там, где важен точный размер переменной*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

с функцией main все очевидно - по стандарту там должен быть тип `int`. Нет никаких указаний о других вариантах. Я думаю, что если кто то напишет что то другое - он удивит остальных.

> Использовать ли int8_t* в строках вместо char*?

не вижу никаких предпосылок этого делать. Опять же, по стандарту, есть упоминание, что тип char должен вмещать код любого символа (как то так).

> Следует ли везде заменять классические типы данных(short, int, long) на платформонезависимые(int16_t, int32_t, int64_t) из <inttypes.h>

а зачем? что бы было красиво?

А когда стоит использовать такие типы? Стоит использовать, когда есть гарантии, что там будет именно указанное кол-во бит - например, при разборе сетевых пакетов, реализации архивирования/шифрования/файловых систем/работы с железом.

А вот при написании лабораторной работы - можно и нужно использовать обычные типы (если чего то другого не написано в задании).

Comment: Еще один вариант, когда их стоит использовать - если код должен собираться без исправлений под разные платформы